# Java Date/time class supported in new workbench Test Scenario?

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

Is there a date/time type supported by the new business central workbench test scenarios? `java.time.LocalDateTime` does not appear to work although for dates java.time.LocalDate does work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no embedded support for `java.time.LocalDateTime` but starting from version 7.30 we support MVEL expressions in RULE based test scenarios: it is enough to add `#` as prefix to the value and then you can invoke the Java method that you prefer.
In EXPECT section you can use an implicit variable named `actualValue` to have access to the value of that column

[image: see screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Support to `LocalDateTime` and `LocalTime` was added since version 7.47.0.